# Get-History don't work

Tags: powershell

I have strange problem with new servers where is installed Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Core (Insider Preview 16257), Powershell 5.1. I can see all the commands used with up and down arrows, but I get nothing with Get-History cmdlet. Even when I enter some new cmdlets, Get-history did nothing at all. I need to save the history. I'm logged in with the same credentials. Thanks

Comment: [Related reading](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh241048.aspx) - those are _different_ "histories"

Comment: You are probably getting the history from the PSReadline module. `(Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath`

Comment: Thank you sodawillow, that brings some light to the dark, I like Don's work very much. BenH, your comment is the right answer! Please create an separate answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Windows 10 / Server 2016, the [PSReadline Module](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) is included by default. This includes it's own per user history file. This file can be found with this command: `(Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath`.

This file is separate that than the per session history that is accessible with the `Get-History` command.